# R Plotly linked subplot with percentage histogram and categories coloured

Tags: r, plotly, visualization, r-plotly

## The Background

I am using the plotly API in R to create two linked plots. The first is a scatter plot and the second is a bar chart that should show the percentage of data belonging to each category, in the current selection. I can't make the percentages behave as expected.

## The problem

The plots render correctly and the interactive selection works fine. When I select a set of data points in the top scatter plot, I would like to see the percentage of that selection that belongs to each category. Instead what I see is the percentage of points in that selection in that category that belong to that category, in other words always 100%. I guess this is because I set `color = ~c` which applies a grouping to the category.

## The Example

Here is a reproducible example to follow. First create some dummy data.

```r
library(plotly)

n = 1000
make_axis = function(n) c(rnorm(n, -1, 1), rnorm(n, 2, 0.25))
data = data.frame(
  x = make_axis(n),
  y = make_axis(n),
  c = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n)
)
```

Create a `sharedData` object and supply it to `plot_ly()` for the base plot.

```r
shared_data = data %>% 
  highlight_key()

baseplot = plot_ly(shared_data)
```

Make the individual panels.

```
points = baseplot %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~c)

bars = baseplot %>% 
  add_histogram(x = ~c, color = ~c, histnorm = "percent", showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group")
```

And put them together in a linked subplot with selection and highlighting.

```
subplot(points, bars) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select") %>% 
  highlight("plotly_selected")
```

Here is a screenshot of this to illustrate the problem.
[image]

## An Aside

Incidentally when I set `histnorm = ""` in `add_histogram()` then I get closer to the expected behaviour but I do want percentages and not counts. When I remove `color = ~c` then I get closer to the expected behaviour but I do want the consistent colour scheme.

## What have I tried

I have tried manually supplying the colours but then some of the linked selection breaks. I have tried creating a separate summarised data set from the `sharedData` object first and then plotting that but again this breaks the linkage between the plots.

If anyone has any clues as to how to solve this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems the behaviour you are looking for isn't implemented in plotly.

Please see `schema()`: object ► traces ► histogram ► attributes ► histnorm ► description

However, here is the closest I was able to achive via `add_bars` and perprocessing the data (Sorry for adding `data.table`, you will be able to do the same in base R, just personal preference):

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

n = 1000
make_axis = function(n) c(rnorm(n, -1, 1), rnorm(n, 2, 0.25))
DT = data.table(
  x = make_axis(n),
  y = make_axis(n),
  c = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n)
)

DT[, grp_percent := rep(100/.N, .N), by = "c"]

shared_data = DT %>% 
  highlight_key()

baseplot = plot_ly(shared_data)
# Make the individual panels.

points = baseplot %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~c)

bars = baseplot %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~c, y = ~grp_percent, color = ~c, showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group")

subplot(points, bars) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select") %>% 
  highlight("plotly_selected")
```

[image: Result]

Unfortunately, the resulting hoverinfo isn't really desirable.

Comment: actually I don't think what you have is quite what I need. You have the proportion of the group in the selection and I need the proportion of the selection belonging to each group.